# bit pack Int16 into a Ushort VB.net

Tags: vb.net, casting, bit-manipulation

I have to pack and unpack a 16bit Int from/into a Ushort in VB.net

This is how I thought I could do it (doesn't work, gives me overflow exception)

```
'Pack Int16 into ushort '
Dim usPacked = CType(Data, UShort)

'unpack Int16 from ushort '
Dim unpacked = CType(data,Int16)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the old Union solution

```
<StructLayout(Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
Structure s1
    <FieldOffset(0)> Public AsShort As Short
    <FieldOffset(0)> Public AsUShort As UShort
End Structure

Dim v1 = GetTheShortValue()   
Dim v2 = new s1
v2.AsShort = v1
Dim v3 As UShort = v2.AsUShort
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [Jared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609532/bit-pack-int16-into-a-ushort-vb-net/1609841#1609841) is better than this one of mine :(

- [UShort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x68bebe2.aspx) can store integers from 0 through 65,535.
- [Short](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tb7bdw6.aspx) can store integers from -32,768 through 32,767.
- [Long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y595sc15.aspx) can store integers from about -2 billion to +2 billion.

You'll get an [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow) when you try to put negative numbers into a UShort, or when you try to put numbers over 32,767 into a Short. One solution is to use a Long as an intermediary.

```
  'Pack Int16 into ushort '  
  Dim usPacked = CType(CLng(nData) + 32768, UShort)    
  'unpack Int16 from ushort '  
  Dim unpacked = CType(CLng(usPacked) - 32768, Int16)
```